# What is the main idea of creating click heatmap?

Tags: algorithm, canvas, svg, heatmap

in one of my projects, I would like to create heatmap of user clicks. I was searching a while and found this library - http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/examples.html . That is basically exactly what I would like to make. I would like to create heatmap in SVG, if possible, that is only difference.

I would like to create my own heatmap and I'm just wondering how to do that. I have XY clicks position. Each click has mostly different XY position, but there can be exceptions time to time, a few clicks can have the came XY position.

I found a few solutions based on grid on website, where you have to check which clicks belong into the same column in this grid and according to these informations you are able to fill the most clicked columns with red or orange and so on. But it seems a little bit complicated to me and maybe slower for bigger grids.

So I'm wondering if there is another solution how to "calculate" heatmap colors or I would like to know the main idea used in library above.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you use `matplotlib`?

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrongly. I would like to know only the way how can be heatmap created, only the main idea of algorithm. Like I wrote above, I have XY click position, but I do not know, how to "group" clicks which are close to each other and set them red color, like "the most clicked place". And of course, also handle the rest of clicks similar way, only the colors will be different according heatmap - red, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to determine which grid should a click position belong to?

Comment: I can determine which click belongs to which grid, but I hope there are another algorithms, except grid. Using grid, it seems to me little bit complicated, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not complicated. It's just two simple division operations.

Comment: I was thinking about that. I could do grid by pixels - for example, area is 10x10 px. Cliks are on coordinates 2x3, 8x1, 10x10, 2x3. First of all, I go through array with coordinates and I find out, that the most clicks are on cooridate 2x3. And what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

To make this kind of heat map, you need some kind of writable array (or, as you put it, a "grid").  User clicks are added onto this array in a cumulative fashion, by adding a small "filter" sub-array (aligned around each click) to the writable array.

Unfortunately, this "grid" method seems to be the easiest, simplest way to get that kind of smooth, blobby appearance.  Fortunately, this kind of operation is well-supported by software and hardware, under the name "computer graphics".

When considered as a computer graphics operation, the writable array is called an "accumulation buffer".  The filter is what gives you the nice blobby appearance, even with a relatively small number of clicks -- you can tweak the size of the filter according to the needs of your application.

After accumulating the user clicks, you will need to convert from the raw accumulated values to some kind of visible color scale.  This may involve looking through the entire accumulation buffer to find the largest value, and mapping your chosen color scale accordingly.  Alternately, you could adjust your scale according to the number of mouse clicks, or (as in the demo you linked to) just choose a fixed scale regardless of the content of the buffer.

Finally, I should mention that SVG is not well-adapted to representing this kind of graphic.  It should probably be saved as some kind of image file (.jpg or .png) instead.